# what will happen to the alloacted memory in a constructor if I throw exception from constructor?

Tags: c++

If I am allocating some memory to a pointer using new in a constructor and if I throw exception after allocating memory form constructor, will the memory will be reclaimed or will it be memory leak?

```
class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
            p = new int(4);
            throw 1;
        }

        ~A()
        {
            delete p;
        }

    private:
        int *p;
};
```

Comment: What do you think happens if you do this *without* throwing an exception? You have a `new` without a `delete` - it's bad regardless.

Comment: As-written this is a memory leak in-wait *regardless* of throwing an exception. And to address your concerns, `std::vector<int> p;`, then `p(4)` on the initializer of the constructor. Then throw all you want. [Pointers should not own resources](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Comment: Ok Joseph. I added destructor

Comment: @kadina A destructor won't help with an exception thrown.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Yeah. I know. But Joseph wants to add destructor :)

Comment: @kadina He just correctly stated _" it's bad regardless"_. `Don't roll memory management your own, unless you really, really, really need it, and are a 100% sure what you're doing.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory will not be reclaimed. Even if you correctly had a destructor (and copy/assignment operator) it would STILL leak the memory.

Any fully constructed sub-objects will be destructed after the throw. In this case `p` would be destructed, which is not to be confused with the memory pointed to by `p` being free: They are two very different things and the memory will in fact be leaked.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think below are the rules

Comment: 1) The destructor for the object being constructed will not be called.
2) Destructors for member objects contained in that object's class will be called
3) The memory for the object that was being constructed will be freed.

Comment: But in that case p is also member variable.